# How to generate bearer token via azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I followed this [blog](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/azure-data-factory-retrieve-token-from-azure-ad-using-oauth-2-0-9a3ed3f55013) for generating bearer token.

I have an API like this `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/token`.

I tested it in postman it's working but it is not working in ADF.

**Error message**

```
"error": "invalid request"
"error description": "xxxx: The 'resource' request parameter is not supported. \r\nTrace ID: xxxxx\rnCorrelation ID: xxxx\r\nTimestamp: xxxx"
"error codes": [
901002
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a screenshot of your webactivity and it's setting as well as the settings on Postman where it worked successfully. The blog doesn't have any resource parameter. It only has SCOPE. Was that the miss from your side?

Answer (score 2):

Yes ,you can use both **resource** and **scope** depending upon endpoint.

If you are using endpoint with  **oauth2/token**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/token`

You need to use `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/` inside the body

**Body:** `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/`

[image]

If you are using **oauth2/v2.0/token** endpoint
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token`

You need to use `scope`:

**Body:**  `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

[image]

**The pipeline successfully executed got the token:**

[image]