# ADF Web Activity to get new Refresh/Access tokens Quickbooks Online

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, quickbooks-online

I am having troubles running a web activity to fetch the new refresh/access tokens from Quickbooks online.

From Postman I keep receiving an "invalid_grant" error, likely since the refresh token changes every 24 hrs (seems excessive to me). From ADF I am getting a "bad_request" error. Does anyone have an example of the Web Activity they used in ADF to capture this info?

If someone could provide an example of the URL, Body and Headers they are using that would be very helpful. Not sure if I am doing something wrong or if this needs to be opened up with the Intuit team. Its most likely because the RefreshToken we have stored in Key Vault is no longer valid, but I want to make sure my Web Activity is formatted correctly first.

I have tried hardcoding the clientId and client secrets using basic authentication to the following url https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer in order to obtain the new tokens

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce the same in my environment using web Activity and generated a bearer Token in Azure data factory.

Use Your  **User id**  and  **Password**  inside Body

[image]

output:

[image]

Alternative approach refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75230149/how-to-generate-bearer-token-via-azure-data-factory/75232048#75232048) thread.