# {"ErrorCode":"invalid_request","Error":"Unsupported grant type : ","token_type":"Bearer"}

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

I am using the same setup I used in Postman, but I am getting an error in Azure data factory! Help me!

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
client_secret:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

The above, I tried inputting in the key value pairs in the body under x-www-form-urlencoded thats the only time it works, not with Bosy->raw->json nor raw->text

I tried the Json format but it doesnt work in both postman and ADF

{
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Both say the error is {"ErrorCode":"invalid_request","Error":"Unsupported grant type : ","token_type":"Bearer"}

But when I enter inputting in the key value pairs in the body -> x-www-form-urlencoded thats the only time it works, but when I use application/x-www-form-urlencoded and used the Key value edit to copy paste the format which was
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
client_secret:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
It still gives me same error in Azure data Factory but seems to work in postman

I tried content type as both text/plain, and application/x-www-form-urlencoded in headers

Answer (score 0):

**To resolve the error. Please follow the below steps:**

**Step1:**  Go to the active directory and check whether created AD application has enough API permission or not.

**Step2:** Create web activity to get bearer token from ADF.

URL : `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant_Id>/oauth2/token`

[image]

**Method :**  POST

Note: Make sure to provide `resource` inside the body.

**Body:**  `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/`

**Header:**  `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

[image]

For more information **refer** this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75230149/how-to-generate-bearer-token-via-azure-data-factory/75232048#75232048) thread.